# Xcode Debug: cannot find 'imageURL' in scope when I can see imageURL in the variable list

Tags: swift, xcode

[image: Xcode debugger error after trying to print object with "po imageURL", however, imageURL is clearly in variable list]

I have been scratching my head for an hour, still cannot figure out why this happens.

Also same issue with string variables defined inside if statements (holdCountString, copyCountString, isbn, upc)

I have tried cleaning build folder, cleaning Xcode cache, restart the computer, and reopen Xcode, however, the debugger still says "cannot find 'imageURL' in scope".

```swift
static func newSearchResult(from record: SwiftSoup.Element) async throws -> SearchResult? {
    let title = try record.select(CSSSelector.title.rawValue).text()
    let author = try record.select(CSSSelector.author.rawValue).text()
    
    let typeString = try record.select(CSSSelector.type.rawValue).text()
    let type = ItemType(rawValue: typeString)
    
    if type == nil {
        return nil
    }
    
    var releaseYear = try record.select(CSSSelector.releaseYear.rawValue).text()
    if releaseYear.last == "." { releaseYear.removeLast() }
    
    let description = try record.select(CSSSelector.description.rawValue).text()
    let itemRelativePath = try record.select(CSSSelector.itemRelativePath.rawValue).attr(AttributeKey.href.rawValue)
    
    var holdCount = 0
    var copyCount = 0
    
    var imageURL: URL? = nil
    let sizeCode = try record.select(CSSSelector.mainImage.rawValue).attr(AttributeKey.imageSizeCode.rawValue)
    
    if type == .ebook {
        let overdriveID = try record.select(CSSSelector.overdriveImage.rawValue).attr(AttributeKey.overdriveID.rawValue)
        
        let availability = try await overdriveAvailability(forID: overdriveID)
        holdCount = availability.holdCount
        copyCount = availability.copyCount
        
        let overdriveImage = try await overdriveCoverImage(forID: overdriveID)
        imageURL = URL(string: overdriveImage.src)
        
    } else if type != .elearning && type != .evideo {
        let holdCountString = try record.select(CSSSelector.holdCount.rawValue).text()
        if holdCountString != "" { holdCount = Int(holdCountString.split(separator: " ")[0])! }
        
        let copyCountString = try record.select(CSSSelector.copyCount.rawValue).text()
        if copyCountString != "" { copyCount = Int(copyCountString.split(separator: " ")[0])! }
        
        let isbn = try record.select(CSSSelector.mainImage.rawValue).attr(AttributeKey.isbn.rawValue)
        let upc = try record.select(CSSSelector.mainImage.rawValue).attr(AttributeKey.upc.rawValue)
        
        imageURL = TPLAPI.syndeticsImageURL(usingISBN: isbn, orUPC: upc, withSizeCode: sizeCode)
    }
    
    return SearchResult(
        imageURL: imageURL, title: title, author: author,
        type: type!, releaseYear: releaseYear,
        description: description, copyCount: copyCount,
        holdCount: holdCount, itemRelativePath: itemRelativePath
    )
}
```

newSearchResult(from:) is called inside another function searchResults(for:) which is in charge of downloading a HTML file, then processing it using SwiftSoup to extract all the container elements for every search result, then use newSearchResult(from:) to process each container element. Both functions are asynchronous.

the search view uses the following code to call searchResults(for:):

```swift
.onSubmit {
    Task {
        do {
            showProgressView.toggle()
                            
            print("task started running for input: \(input)")
                            
            searchResults = try await TPLAPI.searchResults(for: input)
            showProgressView.toggle()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post code as text and not as images. This looks like the debugger is misbehaving rather than a programming issue.

Comment: Restart Xcode and do a clean build.

Comment: @HangarRash tried cleaning build folder, cleaning Xcode cache, restart the computer, and reopen Xcode. no change, still the same error

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, not sure if this is purely the debugger misbehaving, because inside the view in which search results are displayed, no image is displayed for any single search result. Basically this async function is in charge of processing the data contained within a html element which is extracted using SwiftSoup.

Comment: (lldb) frame variable imageURL
(Foundation.URL?) imageURL = <no location, value may have been optimized out>

Comment: but optimization level is set to no optimization for the currently selected Debug scheme.

Comment: also just noticed when execution paused on the breakpoint of line 147 (the one for sizeCode), there is a underline under "rawValue" in "CSSSelector.mainImage.rawValue"

Comment: Xcode debugger "error: cannot find 'variableName' in scope" appeared in my code _after synchronous methods were changed to `async` `await`_. Also, the `variableName` in the variable list no longer shows a value when expanded. A workaround was to use the not-preferred-approach of adding `print(variableName)` to the code. Or, alternately some `log(.debug, variableName)`.  … this is possibly an async/await lldb issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Swift forum thread ["Swift Concurrency / LLDB unable to print object"](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-concurrency-lldb-unable-to-print-object/57115) provides information that there is a known issue between concurrency and the Xcode debugger `LLDB` which causes a `cannot find '…' in scope` error:

> > However in many cases `LLDB` refuses to work for me when im in a Task or concurrently executing context
>
> We can confirm this. We always receive this error message for all async functions (within `Task`). Unfortunately I have not yet found a workaround for this behavior. The root cause is that [self is unavailable](https://forums.swift.org/t/xcode-12-5-cannot-find-lldb-injected-self-in-scope/48650/2).

Until this issue is resolved, a workaround could be something like:

```swift
log(level: .debug, msg: "varName is \(varName)")

// --- or ---

#if DEBUG
print(varName)
#endif
```